# Liquidsoap: how to remove track from playlist?

Tags: linux, bash, streaming, ubuntu-18.04, liquidsoap

I have a goal to stream new files from a directory with Liquidsoap. 
1. Inotify tracks target folder and adds all new files to playlist:

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -e close_write --format '%f' -m "/my/folder" | \
(
while read NEWFILE
do
echo $NEWFILE >> playlist.txt
done
)
```

2. Liquidsoap plays playlist.txt

```
#!/usr/bin/liquidsoap
radio = mksafe(playlist(loop=false,mode='normal',reload=0,reload_mode="watch", "playlist.txt"))
```

3. last step: Liquidsoap should remove track from playlist.txt after it have been played 
Need help with removing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove some track after it has been played just add `prefix="tmp:"`

```
radio = mksafe(playlist(prefix="tmp:",loop=false,mode='normal',reload=0,reload_mode="watch", "playlist.txt"))
```

Comment: Please note the `loop` parameter seems to be not available anymore in the current Liquidsoap 1.4.3.